# Prove that $Z(\overline{G})\cap \ker(\overline{\rho})=\{e_{\overline{G}}\}$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. Consider $K=Z(G)\cap \ker(\rho)$, where $\rho:G \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of $G$. Since $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $K \subset Z(G)$ we can consider the quotients $\overline{G}=G/K$ and $\overline{Z}=Z(G)/K$ and $p:G \rightarrow \overline{G}$ be the canonical projetion. Since $K \subset \ker(\rho)$, from the universal property of the homomorphism, there exists a homomorphism $\overline{\rho}:\overline{G} \rightarrow GL(V)$ such that $\rho=\overline{\rho} \circ p$.

**My question:** Is it true that $Z(\overline{G})\cap \ker(\overline{\rho})=\{e_{\overline{G}}\}$?

**My attempt:** If $aK \in Z(\overline{G})\cap \ker(\overline{\rho})$ in order to prove that $aK=eK$ we have to show that $a \in K$. Indeed, $\rho(a)=\overline{\rho}(p(a))=\overline{\rho}(aK)=Id_V$, since $aK \in \ker(\overline{\rho})$. Therefore, $a \in \ker{\rho}$. However, I was unable to prove that $a \in Z(G)$. I tried to use that $\ker(\overline{\rho})=p(\ker(\rho))$.

Comment: Why might you expect this to be true? What if $\rho$ is the trivial representation for example, so $\ker \rho = G$?

Comment: @DerekHolt And if we assume that $Z(G) \cap \ker(\rho)=\{e\}$?

Comment: In this case holds, since $aga^{-1}g^{-1} \in K=\{e\}$ for all $g \in G$, that is, $a \in Z(G)$ .

Answer (score 1):

My answer is no. The essential idea is that $\bar{Z}(G)$ and $Z(\bar G)$ might not have a direct relationship (that I know of). Let's consider the following example:

$G=D_4=\langle s,r|s^2=1, r^4=1, srs=r^{-1}\rangle $ the dihedral group of size $8$. Let $\rho$ sends $s$ to $-1$ and $r$ to $1$, giving a 1-dimensional representation.

Now $\ker \rho=\langle r \rangle$, $Z(G)=\langle r^2 \rangle$ so $K=\langle r^2 \rangle$. $\bar G$ has size 4 is abelian, so $Z(\bar{G})=\bar G$. It's easy to see that $\ker(\bar \rho)=\{G,rG\}$ so their intersection is not trivial.

Comment: Or you can just take $\rho$ to be the trivial representation.